# Error while binding combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to bind a combobox using dataset, but the values are not setting in the combobox and instead of that it shows system.data.datarowview. I search for this and none of the answers are right. I am using the following code

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    cmb_usrname.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    cmb_usrname.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["usrName"].ToString();
    cmb_usrname.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["userId"].ToString(); 
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,53,0,0" Name="cmb_usrname" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

thanks ,

sivajith

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` to column names

```
cmb_usrname.DisplayMemberPath = "usrName";
cmb_usrname.SelectedValuePath = "userId";
```

since this is fixed you might as well do it in XAML

```
<ComboBox ... DisplayMemberPath="usrName" SelectedValuePath="userId"/>
```

Comment: So it still displays `System.Data.DataRowView`? Both methods work fine for me. Make sure this is actually set.

Comment: This happens when theme is applied. Other wise the combobox shows all the data.

Comment: That means you have also problem in `Template` that you're using for `ComboBox`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has already been answered. Please look at one of my other answers for this problem 
[Binding Datasource View to Datagrid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871254/binding-datasource-view-to-datagrid-in-wpf/26873025#26873025)

[WPF DataTrigger doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759367/wpf-datatrigger-doesnt-work/26763721#26763721)

The highlights are:
1) your backing cs file needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged
2) In the xmal file set the `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`
3) In your combobox set the `itemsSource="{Bind SomeProperty}"`
4) In your backing cs file have a property of `ObservableCollection<SomeType>`
5) When the property get updated call `NotifyPropertyChanged`